# How to run multiple Golang apps on a dedicated server?

Tags: go, web-applications, server

I'm a Go newbie and I'm stuck trying to figure out how to deploy my apps on a dedicated server.

When I worked with PHP I used the standard setup:

[image: Apache and PHP diagram]

But I'm confused as to how I'm supposed to deploy my Go apps.

I know I can run a single app on port `:80` but how do I run multiple apps?

Is this the general idea:

[image: Multiple apps diagram]

Or should I be using something like this:

[image: Nginx diagram]

Can someone clarify the way most Go developers deploy their apps? 
Thanks!

Comment: If you want multiple apps on port 80 then a proper webserver fronting your applications is a good way to go.  Nginx or Apache should handle that easily (my preference being Nginx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd highly recommend going with Caddy.  You can set up you server with all the apps on different ports (esp. higher ports i.e. 1024 and up, so they don't need to be root), and then use `proxy` directives to forward traffic to your apps and such.  As a bonus, you also then get free Let's Encrypt certificate support!

https://caddyserver.com/docs/proxy for more on the `proxy` directive

Answer (score 3):

If you need multiple apps to serve HTTP requests, you should definitely consider using Nginx as a [reverse proxy](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/). You can forward all requests on a given route, say /api to one service and /ui to a second service, provided they are bound to different ports.

Comment: Moreover, with this setup Go programs can be set to listen on a [Unix-domain socket](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass); passing data between UD-sockets is super fast as it merely amounts to copying data between memory buffers (as opposed to letting it through the full TCP stack).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look a Traefik (https://traefik.io/), a go based web proxy